# Python's Class Inheritance

Tags: python, class, inheritance

```
# Defining a Base class to be shared among many other classes later:

class Base(dict):
    """Base is the base class from which all the class will derrive.
    """
    name = 'name'    
    def __init__( self):
        """Initialise Base Class
        """
        dict.__init__(self)
        self[Base.name] = ""

# I create an instance of the Base class:

my_base_instance = Base()

# Since a Base class inherited from a build in 'dict' the instance of the class is a dictionary. I can print it out with:

print my_base_instance   Results to: {'name': ''}


# Now I am defining a Project class which should inherit from an instance of Base class:

class Project(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "OK"
        self['id'] = ''

# Trying to create an instance of Project class and getting the error:

project_class = Project(base_class)

TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: You have to declare inheritence when defining the class (`class Project(Base)` and not when instantiating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two mistakes in your code:

1) Class inheritance

```
class Project(Base):   # you should inherit from Base here...
    def __init__(self):
        print "OK"
        self['id'] = ''
```

2) Instance definition (your `__init__` does not requires any explicit parameter, and for sure not the ancestor class)

```
project_class = Project() # ...and not here since this is an instance, not a Class
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're instantiating a class, you don't need to pass in `base_class`. That's done at definition. `__init__` takes exactly 1 argument, which is `self`, and automatic. You just need to call

```
project_class = Project()
```

Answer (score 1):

For Project to inherit from Base, you should not subclass it from object but from Base i.e `class Project(Base)`. You get `TypeError: init() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)` error when you instantiate  Project class because the constructor takes only 1 parameter(`self`) and you pass `base_class` too. `'self'` is passed implicitly by python.